# Trouble with a simple GetElementById thing real simple

Tags: javascript

Real simple but I'm starting with javascript so it should be quickly soved

I have this html:

```
<body>
<div id="content">
        <div id="logo">
            <noscript>
            <img src="fin_palais.png"/>
            </noscript>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
```

and i want to select the div with an id of "logo" with javascript to then overwrite the `<noscript>` with the apropriate file ( a simple browser test to see if you can support SVG )
this innerHTML look like this:

```
document.getElementById('logo').innerHTML='<content to be added>';
```

Firebug send me this error: *TypeError: document.getElementById("logo") is null*
but its right there!
Thanks

okay so here is the full HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <META CHARSET="UTF-8">
    <title>Bienvenu au Fin Palais</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="svg_support.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">getSvgSupport("fin_palais")</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
        <div id="logo">

            <noscript>
            <img src="fin_palais.png"/>
            </noscript>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the full svg_support.js I've made;

```
function getSvgSupport(file)
            {

                var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        if( ua.indexOf("Android") >= 0 )
            {
          var androidversion = parseFloat(ua.slice(ua.indexOf("Android")+8)); 
          if (androidversion <= 2.3)
                {
                document.getElementById('logo').innerHTML='<img src="',file,'.png"/>';

                }


            } else {
                document.getElementById('logo').innerHTML='<!--[if lt IE 9]><img src="',file,'.png"/><![endif]--><!--[if gte IE 9]><!--><embed src="',file,'.svg" type="image/svg+xml" /><!--<![endif]-->';
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is your JavaScript code inside window.onload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes that is the only reason, and since you seem new to javascript I guess this would make more sense to you

```
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById('logo').innerHTML='<content to be added>';
}
```

You see when your script runs you page has not loaded. so you must use window.onload.

Or you can use this too, if your code is in file.js:

```
<script defer src="file.js"> </script>
```

this makes sure your code doesn't run unless document is parsed.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know about that `defer` trick. I wasn't expecting to learn something from this question! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may be trying to run the javascript before the DOM has finished loading. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){document.getElementById('logo').innerHTML='<content to be added>';});
```

This assumes you've included jQuery.

As @Thristhart said, you can also use `window.onload`. This is a built-in javascript event which happens AFTER `$(document).ready()` does, so you should be safe with that as well.

Comment: alternatively, if you're not using jQuery, you can simply use
`window.onload = function() { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

If using JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div#logo').html('<content to be added>');
});
```

Or

```
$(function(){
    $('div#logo').html('<content to be added>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to load jQuery if you don't want to it seems like something is off with the chaining of the javascript.  When I broke it apart it worked fine.

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/DamianHall/GxghG/

```
var ele = document.getElementById('logo');

ele.innerHTML = 'content to be added';
```

Looking at other posts it is an onload issue.  The JS fiddle did the onload for me so I didn't notice.​